# Usage of Criteria Builder with not in on joined field

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, spring-data, criteria

I have a Hotel entity & HotelReservation entity.

I try to fetch available Hotels to make a reservation.

**Idea**:

Fetch All Hotels and remove which are not available. (Hotel is not available if it's reserved in a certain time - in function, there are parameters `from` -> `to`). I followed the examples on stackoverflow.com and produce this code:

```
fun availableHotelsBetweenDates(from: ZonedDateTime, to: ZonedDateTime): Specification<Hotel> = Specification<Hotel> { root, query, cb ->
    val reservationsBetweenDates: Subquery<HotelReservation> = query.subquery(HotelReservation::class.java)
    val subqueryRoot = reservationsBetweenDates.from(HotelReservation::class.java)

    val join: Join<Hotel, HotelReservation> = root.join("reservations", JoinType.LEFT)

    reservationsBetweenDates.select(subqueryRoot.get("id"))
    reservationsBetweenDates.where(activeReservationsBetweenDates(from, to).toPredicate(subqueryRoot, query, cb))
    reservationsBetweenDates.distinct(true)
    cb.not(join.get<Long>("id").`in`(reservationsBetweenDates))
}
```

This function returns 0 entities (should return 2 - because I have 3 hotels and only one reservation for one hotel).
Function `activeReservationsBetweenDates(from, to`) return a `Specification<HotelReservation>` of all HotelReservation between `from`, `to`.

How to properly use **not in**, with subquery on nested field?